# javascript picture zoom in and zoom out

Tags: javascript

i try to créate a javascript class for zoom in and zoom out some pictures.
But all pictures of the page zoom in and zoom out. I think it's a javascript loop's problem but i cant do it.
This is my Class , someone see the problem ?

class Image {

```
constructor() {
    this.ip = document.getElementsByClassName("image_petite");
    this.images = [];
}

agrandir() {
   
    for (let i=0; i < this.ip.length; i++) {
        this.images.push(this.ip[i]);
        };

    console.log(this.images);

for (let j=0; j < this.images.length; j++) {
    if (this.images[j].classList == "image_petite") { 
    
        this.images[j].classList.remove('image_petite');
        this.images[j].classList.add('image_grande');
        
        
        } else if (this.images[j].classList == "image_grande") {
        this.images[j].classList.remove('image_grande');
        this.images[j].classList.add('image_petite');
        }
        }            
}
```

}

```
let image = new Image();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 3):

`this.images[j].classList == "image_petite"` isn't how you check to see if an element has a class. Instead, you use [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains):

```
if (this.images[j].classList.contains("image_petite")) {
    // ...
}
```

Separately, though, you've used a loop, which intentionally processes everything in the `this.images` array. It's hard to say what you should do instead without knowing what the DOM structure (loosely, the HTML) looks like, but if you're trying to handle resizing **one** image, you'll need to identify the image you want to resize, which nothing in that code does.

Here's a simple example using a `click` handler:

```js
// This example uses event delegation
document.body.addEventListener("click", event => {
    const image = event.target.closest("img");
    if (image && event.currentTarget.contains(image)) {
        // This is the image to enlarge or toggle
        if (image.classList.contains("image_grand")) {
            // Toggling it from big back to small
            image.classList.remove("image_grand");
            image.classList.add("image_petite");
        } else {
            // Making this the one big one
            const big = document.querySelector(".image_grand");
            if (big) {
                // Make the current big one small again
                big.classList.remove("image_grand");
                big.classList.add("image_petite");
            }
            // Make this one big
            image.classList.add("image_grand");
            image.classList.remove("image_petite");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.image_petite {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
.image_grand {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="image_petite" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080 ?text=1">
</div>
<div>
    <img class="image_petite" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080 ?text=2">
</div>
<div>
    <img class="image_petite" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080 ?text=3">
</div>
```

That said, I think I'd use just a single class and add/remove that class, rather than two classes.